# Is it possible to have a Dictionary where the value for a given key/value pair is enforced to be of a specific type based on the key?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, collections

Specifically I am trying to create a dictionary with keys of type PropertyInfo and a value that is a List that I would like to enforce as containing objects of the same type as the associated Property described by the key. In other words, a dictionary that describes a set of properties and values to assign to them.

I know that I can simply use a list of Objects, but as far as I can tell, that forces me to perform my check for validity of the contained list types at run-time and also forces me to check every member of the list.

Ideally, I'd instead like this to be enforced at compile time rather than run time and/or to remove the need for verifying ever individual member of the list. I am ok with getting a compile time error if the compiler cannot actually determine the property's type at compile time (my particular use case deals with properties that will be known).

I suspect this may not be possible due to the issue of the compiler not having a way to always be certain of the type that the property will have prior to run time, but I'm hoping I missed something that may allow for it.

Comment: You could create a class yourself with constrains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't missed anything. It's impossible since there is no property type info associated with `PropertyInfo` at compile time. It's even not a generic type (like `List<T>`).

Comment: I was hoping something clever could be done by the compiler for scenarios where where the value of the PropertyInfo and consequently its type information could be determined prior to run-time, but in retrospect such scenarios would be vanishingly rare due to various complications that could arise due to changes that could occur but not force a re-compile that also invalidate a determination that was previously correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dictionary<PropertyInfo, dynamic>`, but it's not going to be able to be checked at compile time. You can create a value for a given key by doing:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Property { get; set; }
}

var dict = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, dynamic>();
var propertyInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Property));

dict.Add(propertyInfo, Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(propertyInfo.PropertyType)));
```

`dict[propertyInfo].GetType()` is `List<int>`, but you're not going to get Intellisense with it as it is `dynamic`.